# When is an instance member created?

Tags: java, reference

I have 2 pieces of code from Java:

```
class Test1 {
  index = 1;
  int index;
}
```

versus

```
class Test2 {
  { index = 1; }
  int index; 
}
```

the first one failed when compiling, I guess it's because the member "index" is used before it is defined? The second one is error-free. I don't understand why. Can you guys spare some minutes and help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: Sorry , it's Java, I have editted my post. Thansk!

Comment: There are no references here, just primitive types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second one compiles, because that { ... } inner construction present in the second code is a so-called [initializer block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). This block is copied into each constructor by Java compiler.

And, as any other class method, it can use a property defined in that class; it shouldn't matter where exactly this property is defined - above or before this block.

The first one does not compile, because it simply does not fit into the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6) for class bodies and member declarations, which defines basically seven allowed things:

1. InstanceInitializer (the construct used here)
2. StaticInitializer (similar to first, but executed on class loading)
3. ConstructorDeclaration
4. FieldDeclaration
5. MethodDeclaration
6. ClassDeclaration
7. InterfaceDeclaration

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test2 {
  { index = 1; }
  int index; 
}
```

In the above code `{ index = 1; }` is known as `Instance initializer block`, which is used to **intialize the instance variables** of the class **as** `static initializer block` does for **static variables of the class**.

`Java Compiler` will **copy this block into every** `constructor`, making it easy for every constructor to share this block of code......

So **irrespective of the placement** of `instance variable` in the class, (ie. before or after) the `Instance initializer block`, it still can be accessed.

**See this link:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1):

the test2 is compile because use of Initiallizer,it is compile because initiallizer is called before calling of any constructor.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Another way of initializing variables in Java, instead of using a constructor, is to use initializers. Those curly braces in Test2 (*{index = 1;}*) is an initializer, and it's called after *index* has been created. Test1 tries to give value to a variable that has not been declared yet (*index = 1;*).